# Associations and hashmaps in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 4 classes. 
One holds information about a customer. The other one about orders.
2 more classes play the registry role, one is customer registry, the other is orders registry.

Orders registry has a hashmap which looks like this:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Order> orderRegistryMap = new HashMap<>();
```

The same goes for customers registry.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Customer> customersRegistryMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Class orders has an int orderid. Class customers has an int customerid.
I added demo data through both registries (lets say 1 customer with customerid 100, and one order with orderid 500.

I wrote simple methods to search for orders by orderid or to get a hashmap of all orders.
I also wrote simple methods to search for customers by customerid or to get a hashmap of all customers.

I need help with writing a method which can find a customer by orderid and get all orders which are associated with that customerid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post what you tried, and how it didn't work out.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't see how I can link these without writing a method which iterates through keys until it finds a match. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Did you, by any chance come across the [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) function defined in [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? I'd recommend looking up what hash, and hashmap mean, and how to utilize them. Not to mention all you can read about [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) (and once there, [Object.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals()) )

Comment: ppeterka is right you need to show us what have you tried and possibly an example of your data what would you expect the result should be.

Comment: Of course I did, I wrote the methods which get the values based on the keys using this get() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to handle such relations(and this seems like a one to many realtion) is to store a customer id in the order itself. This is done because each order has one and only one customer. if you don't do that you have no choice but iterate through the array.

EDIT: for the reverse relation Customer->Orders I would use a reverse registry something like:

```
HashMap<Integer/*customer_id*/, 
        List<Integer> /*list of orders for the customer*/> customer_orders;
```

And keep that in sync with the orders and customers. This will perform as fast as you can get and I don't think you can use less memory to achieve what you want.

Comment: I did this when I started. The order data contains the customer number.

However, once I select a customer and load its data, I don't see how I can find the associated orders because there is no association from customers to orders, only from orders to customers.

If I was to load an order, finding a customer which made the order would be easy because the customerid is there.

How do I turn this into a two way street? :)

Comment: So you already have a solution of the first problem you have - you can find the customer for each order. As for the second request I would build an index or a HashMap that contains the opposite mapping:
`HashMap<Integer/*customer_id*/, List<Integer> /*list of orders for the customer*/>` and keep that in sync too. I don't think much can be optimized here and also i doubt you can do it using less memory.